# Drupal 7 Views and custom Modules?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I have implemented several custom modules which essentially bridge Drupal with some third party applications we build in house.

Now as my knowledge of Drupal grows I am curious to know whether or not it is possible to integrate my modules with Drupal VIEWS for reporting purposes.

My modules connect directly to several MySQL databases on an external server and perform queries and render those results within the context of Drupal.

What I would like to do, is use VIEWS somehow to SELECT and manipulate the query as a Drupal VIEW to avoid having to re-purpose the module queries each time a change is requested.

Basically, is it possible to expose the SQL tables in an external app to one which Drupal VIEWS can pick up? I have googled and found a few suggestions but no one seems to know for sure???

It seems drupal expects all content to be of it's own internal "content type" and thus connected to it's core "node" - is this an assumption VIEWS makes?

I don't want to export my third party data into Drupal "nodes, content types, etc" simply so VIEWS can effectively read and render the results.

Seems to me, this should be possible with a Drupal module bridging the gap somehow???

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use data module http://drupal.org/project/data

It gives you option to use views on your custom tables. I hope this helps you.

Comment: This is still in alpha, surely not suitable for live use?